# Syntax error: newline unexpected node.js rpm

Tags: linux, node.js

I am running node.js on my Linux Debian server and am having problems running a .sh script trying to install RPM.

The command is:
`curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

The script is a supported install RPM package.

`-bash: sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected`

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Download the script. Look inside it. Does it match what you need? If not, don't use it.

Comment: Are you sure it's RPM, not NPM?

Answer (score 18):

Use this:

```
curl -k https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

**Note:** [npm included](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/README.md) in new versions of node.js. No need to install it separately now.

Comment: npm-install-24639.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected Again!

I did wget https://npmjs.org/install.sh
sh install.sh

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
curl -O https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh
sudo sh install.sh
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508817/3290121).