# Cannot install NPM using curl

Tags: bash, node.js, npm

Receiving this error when attempting to install NPM. Any help on this error is greatly appreciated.

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    85    0    85    0     0   2226      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4473
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: line 1: `<html>Moved: <a href="https://npmjs.org/install.sh">https://npmjs.org/install.sh</a>'
```

Changed the command from http://... --> https:// and still no luck.

---

Other info:

**OS: Mac OSX 10.8.2**

**CURL: curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0)**

---

**So I attempted the install as a superuser and was promptly met with this mountain of text. I'm completely lost here.**

```
$ sudo curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
Password:
#!/bin/sh

# A word about this shell script:
#
# It must work everywhere, including on systems that lack
# a /bin/bash, map 'sh' to ksh, ksh97, bash, ash, or zsh,
# and potentially have either a posix shell or bourne
# shell living at /bin/sh.
#
# See this helpful document on writing portable shell scripts:
# http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Portable-Shell.html
#
# The only shell it won't ever work on is cmd.exe.

if [ "x$0" = "xsh" ]; then
  # run as curl | sh
  # on some systems, you can just do cat>npm-install.sh
      # which is a bit cuter.  But on others, &1 is already closed,
  # so catting to another script file won't do anything.
  curl -s https://npmjs.org/install.sh > npm-install-$$.sh
  sh npm-install-$$.sh
  ret=$?
  rm npm-install-$$.sh
  exit $ret
fi

# See what "npm_config_*" things there are in the env,
# and make them permanent.
# If this fails, it's not such a big deal.
configures="`env | grep 'npm_config_' | sed -e 's|^npm_config_||g'`"

npm_config_loglevel="error"
if [ "x$npm_debug" = "x" ]; then
  (exit 0)
else
  echo "Running in debug mode."
  echo "Note that this requires bash or zsh."
  set -o xtrace
  set -o pipefail
  npm_config_loglevel="verbose"
fi
export npm_config_loglevel

# make sure that node exists
node=`which node 2>&1`
ret=$?
    if [ $ret -eq 0 ] && [ -x "$node" ]; then
  (exit 0)
    else
  echo "npm cannot be installed without nodejs." >&2
  echo "Install node first, and then try again." >&2
  echo "" >&2
  echo "Maybe node is installed, but not in the PATH?" >&2
  echo "Note that running as sudo can change envs." >&2
  echo ""
  echo "PATH=$PATH" >&2
  exit $ret
fi

# set the temp dir
TMP="${TMPDIR}"
if [ "x$TMP" = "x" ]; then
  TMP="/tmp"
fi
TMP="${TMP}/npm.$$"
rm -rf "$TMP" || true
mkdir "$TMP"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "failed to mkdir $TMP" >&2
  exit 1
fi

BACK="$PWD"

ret=0
tar="${TAR}"
if [ -z "$tar" ]; then
  tar="${npm_config_tar}"
fi
if [ -z "$tar" ]; then
  tar=`which tar 2>&1`
  ret=$?
fi

if [ $ret -eq 0 ] && [ -x "$tar" ]; then
  echo "tar=$tar"
  echo "version:"
      $tar --version
  ret=$?
fi

if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
  (exit 0)
else
  echo "No suitable tar program found."
      exit 1
    fi



# Try to find a suitable make
# If the MAKE environment var is set, use that.
# otherwise, try to find gmake, and then make.
# If no make is found, then just execute the necessary commands.

# XXX For some reason, make is building all the docs every time.  This
    # is an annoying source of bugs. Figure out why this happens.
MAKE=NOMAKE

if [ "x$MAKE" = "x" ]; then
  make=`which gmake 2>&1`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ -x $make ]; then
(exit 0)
  else
make=`which make 2>&1`
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ -x $make ]; then
  (exit 0)
else
  make=NOMAKE
fi
  fi
else
  make="$MAKE"
fi

if [ -x "$make" ]; then
  (exit 0)
else
  # echo "Installing without make. This may fail." >&2
      make=NOMAKE
fi

# If there's no bash, then don't even try to clean
if [ -x "/bin/bash" ]; then
  (exit 0)
else
  clean="no"
fi

node_version=`"$node" --version 2>&1`
ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "You need node to run this program." >&2
  echo "node --version reports: $node_version" >&2
  echo "with exit code = $ret" >&2
  echo "Please install node before continuing." >&2
  exit $ret
fi

t="${npm_install}"
    if [ -z "$t" ]; then
  # switch based on node version.
  # note that we can only use strict sh-compatible patterns here.
  case $node_version in
    0.[0123].* | v0.[0123].*)
  echo "You are using an outdated and unsupported version of" >&2
  echo "node ($node_version).  Please update node and try again." >&2
  exit 99
  ;;
v0.[45].* | 0.[45].*)
  echo "install npm@1.0"
  t=1.0
  ;;
v0.[678].* | 0.[678].*)
  echo "install npm@1.1"
  t=1.1
  ;;
*)
  echo "install npm@latest"
  t="latest"
  ;;
  esac
fi

# the npmca cert
cacert='
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
'

echo "$cacert" > "$TMP/cafile.crt"
cacert="$TMP/cafile.crt"

# need to echo "" after, because Posix sed doesn't treat EOF
# as an implied end of line.
url=`(curl -SsL --cacert "$cacert" https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/$t; echo "") \
 | sed -e 's/^.*tarball":"//' \
 | sed -e 's/".*$//'`

ret=$?
if [ "x$url" = "x" ]; then
  ret=125
  # try without the -e arg to sed.
  url=`(curl -SsL --cacert "$cacert" https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/$t; echo "") \
   | sed 's/^.*tarball":"//' \
   | sed 's/".*$//'`
  ret=$?
  if [ "x$url" = "x" ]; then
ret=125
  fi
fi
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to get tarball url for npm/$t" >&2
  exit $ret
fi


echo "fetching: $url" >&2

cd "$TMP" \
  && curl -SsL --cacert "$cacert" "$url" \
 | $tar -xzf - \
  && rm "$cacert" \
  && cd "$TMP"/* \
  && (req=`"$node" bin/read-package-json.js package.json engines.node`
  if [ -d node_modules ]; then
    "$node" node_modules/semver/bin/semver -v "$node_version" -r "$req"
    ret=$?
  else
    "$node" bin/semver.js -v "$node_version" -r "$req"
    ret=$?
  fi
  if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "You need node $req to run this program." >&2
    echo "node --version reports: $node_version" >&2
    echo "Please upgrade node before continuing." >&2
    exit $ret
  fi) \
  && (ver=`"$node" bin/read-package-json.js package.json version`
  isnpm10=0
  if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
    req=`"$node" bin/read-package-json.js package.json engines.node`
    if [ -d node_modules ]; then
      if "$node" node_modules/semver/bin/semver -v "$ver" -r "1"
      then
        isnpm10=1
      fi
    else
      if "$node" bin/semver -v "$ver" -r ">=1.0"; then
        isnpm10=1
      fi
    fi
  fi

  ret=0
  if [ $isnpm10 -eq 1 ] && [ -f "scripts/clean-old.sh" ]; then
    if [ "x$skipclean" = "x" ]; then
      (exit 0)
    else
      clean=no
    fi
    if [ "x$clean" = "xno" ] \
        || [ "x$clean" = "xn" ]; then
      echo "Skipping 0.x cruft clean" >&2
      ret=0
    elif [ "x$clean" = "xy" ] || [ "x$clean" = "xyes" ]; then
      NODE="$node" /bin/bash "scripts/clean-old.sh" "-y"
      ret=$?
    else
      NODE="$node" /bin/bash "scripts/clean-old.sh" </dev/tty
      ret=$?
    fi
  fi

  if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Aborted 0.x cleanup.  Exiting." >&2
    exit $ret
  fi) \
  && (if [ "x$configures" = "x" ]; then
    (exit 0)
  else
    echo "./configure "$configures
    echo "$configures" > npmrc
  fi) \
  && (if [ "$make" = "NOMAKE" ]; then
    (exit 0)
  elif "$make" uninstall install; then
    (exit 0)
  else
    make="NOMAKE"
  fi
  if [ "$make" = "NOMAKE" ]; then
    "$node" cli.js rm npm -gf
    "$node" cli.js install -gf
  fi) \
  && cd "$BACK" \
  && rm -rf "$TMP" \
  && echo "It worked"

ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "It failed" >&2
fi
exit $ret
```

Comment: That's all ? No OS, no curl version, no shell name/version ?

Comment: @sputnick , updated with OS and Curl version. Not sure what you mean by shell name/version..I'm using iTerm if that helps. I've also added what happens when I run the command in su.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are getting the install.sh script, you just have to execute it. Do this

```
curl -O https://npmjs.org/install.sh
sudo sh install.sh
```

---

**Update**

If you get a 301 Moved Permanently file instead, try adding -L option to follow the redirect like this:

```
curl -O -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh
```

Comment: doesn't work downloads a nginx file with `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>`

Comment: @ThomasReggi Your problem seems completely different from the one asked in the question. Also this worked for me. You should ask a new question giving the details of your problem.

Comment: @ThomasReggi See the updated answer if it works for you.

Comment: Just a thought, why not use `-L` all the time?

Comment: @b.long Generally, following redirection always may not be what you want. For this question it would be appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @user568109 Fair enough, sorry I meant "_all the time_" with respect to NPM's install, not literally *every* time.  Thanks :)

Comment: Can we install specific version of npm this way?

Comment: @RavshanSamandarov Yes, set npm_install to that version before executing
export npm_install=6.14.13
sh install.sh

Answer (score 2):

The original command would work if you use the current location (and not the old one) (at least on my system, same settings).
Meaning, use:

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

instead of:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: This doesn't work - hitting the http:/ location returns explicit instructions to use https:/

Comment: @mmmeff Did you read the solution? I specifically mentioned you should use https and NOT http.

Comment: Official gist says to use ```curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh```. 
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many times with various curl options. But the main problem is npm site's https certificate verification. Finally this has worked for me:

```
curl -k -O -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh
```

Hope it will help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

This is still broken somehow? Trying following:

```
$curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    93    0    93    0     0     78      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    79
sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: line 1: `<html>Moved: <a href="https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh">https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh</a>'
```

and with (https) www.npmjs.org :

```
$curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6707  100  6707    0     0   6446      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  6442
npm-install-606.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
npm-install-606.sh: line 1: `<html>Moved: <a href="https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh">https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh</a>'
```

Using OS X Maverics 10.9.1

```
$uname -a
Darwin Esan-iMac.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$curl --version
curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
```

Should it work with similar env; someone tested???
Am I missing something. Remembering that it is discouraged to run with sudo?
Not yet tried separate download and 'sh'-command.

---

Edit: yes, separate download `curl -O https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh` and `sh install.sh` works fine, after changing owner for `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` because previously installed with `sudo`. But it has nothing to do with error message, or  can it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-L` helped me. For example:

```
curl -L http://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508817/1979882
In my case, for Debian OS it is important to create a symbol link:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

More detailed installation workflow is [here](https://blog.slava.online/nodejs-npm-nginx-setup-for-debian/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already install nvm, all you have to do is run nvm install version 
For example if you are willing to install version 8.0.0, then you run 
->$ nvm install 8.0.0
then
->$ nvm use 8.0.0 
 and you can run all your npm commands....