# npm disappeared after running update

Tags: node.js, npm

I was following a tutorial over at [nettutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-infrastructure-part-2/), and after running npm update -g npm, my npm no longer exists when i type which npm. here are the errors. what went wrong and how can i fix it?

```
localhost:~ macgeekalex$ npm update -g npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.3.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.3.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.1.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back  npm@1.3.1 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g" "npm"
npm ERR! cwd /Volumes/Prodigy RAIDER PRO/Users/macgeekalex
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.32
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Volumes/Prodigy RAIDER PRO/Users/macgeekalex/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I think you should simply reinstall it.

Comment: i solved this by reinstalling using the package from node.js (OS X). however, for future reference, how can i update npm from the command line?

Comment: @thetrystero run it as root: `sudo npm update -g npm`

Comment: since the npm diestro is now in the node.js distro you muste update the package or use the installer again(which will only upgrade you current distro). you shouldn't npm update -g npm

Comment: I found an answer I believe for the same problem here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735653/npm-was-installed-i-attempt-to-update-and-find-its-no-longer-installed/37735766#37735766)

Answer (score 19):

See the [FAQ](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/doc/cli/faq.md#how-do-i-update-npm)

> ### How do I update npm?
>
> ```
> npm update npm -g
> ```
>
> npm update npm -g You can also update all
>   outdated local packages by doing npm update without any arguments, or
>   global packages by doing npm update -g.
>
> Occasionally, the version of npm will progress such that the current
>   version cannot be properly installed with the version that you have
>   installed already. (Consider, if there is ever a bug in the update
>   command.)
>
> In those cases, you can do this:
>
> curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

**Update**

The install script location has been moved since, so try:

> curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

Comment: Notice that the right url is now https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh (add 'www.' don't know why)

Comment: If this line doesn't work, [they](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4099#issuecomment-42235606) suggest to use `curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

Comment: @NaoiseGolden Thanks for reminding me, I answered this part in another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508118/cannot-install-npm-using-curl/15508817).

Comment: I had to run as root, but without the trailing dash: `curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` Thanks!