# NPM was installed. I attempt to update and find it's no longer installed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed Node on El Capitan using the [package from their website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

I check to see if `npm` is installed and it shows version `2.15.5` is installed.

I then routinely check to see if there's an update and accidentally forget to use `sudo`. I retry again using `sudo` and it fails saying `npm` command isn't found.

Both `which npm` and `whereis npm` fail to return anything.

What's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your npm upgrade failed, which means that either:

the symlink /usr/local/bin/npm that pointed to the actual script was removed, but it failed when trying to remove the actual npm files and hence, never reinstalled a new symlink

the /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm stuff actually got removed, but not the folder, hence the upgrade failed.

npm should point like this from /usr/local/bin:

`npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

Hope that helps. If the actual npm-cli.js file is actually gone, your best bet is to just re-install node and then upgrade with sudo.