# How to install Meteorite in Meteor?

Tags: linux, meteor, centos

I need to install the Meteorite software package in Meteor.

Environment is : **Linux (Cent OS)**

I am trying the commands below, but it gets an error. I don't understand about doing this. So, please see the below code and suggest how to accomplish installing meteorite software package into meteor.

```
[root@localhost myapp]# npm install -g meteorite
bash: npm: command not found
[root@localhost myapp]#
```

Comment: Look at this SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508118/cannot-install-npm-using-curl . That should get npm installed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously you have not installed the `npm` command which is why cou get the complaint about the fact that this command is missing. I suggest you install that command. Use your local software management system to find the package and install it with a single click.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to install npm (is its download manually or executes from command prompt).@arkascha.

Comment: Actually that is exactly what I wrote in my answer: how to install it. You state that you are working on a RadHat based system. Like most distributions RedHat comes with a software management system which is used to install software. How else did you install packages onto that system? By doing a "wild installation", so downloading from some arbitrary web site and executing some unknown installer with administrative permissions over your system? I hope not!

Comment: `npm` is part of the `node.js` package. Your software management system should be able to find it and offer it for installation. That is what I meant with "install with a single click", because you just have to select it and confirm the installation. After that you will have the `npm` executable available on your system and should be able to use it right away. That would be the clean and secure way to install node.js and npm with it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're receiving from bash ("npm: command not found") indicates that bash can't find npm.  This could either be because it's not installed, or because it's been moved or put in the wrong place.

Have you installed Node.js on your machine, or did you just run the Meteor install script?  Meteor runs on top of Node.js, which is a server-side JavaScript engine.  Npm is the package management tool for Node, and should come with it by default.

[This article from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit) goes over how to install Node on CentOS.  I'd suggest having a look at that.