# Installing NodeJS without sudo in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have already followed [node-and-npm-in-30-seconds.sh](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814).

Earlier I used to create AngularJS application using Yeoman and bower with NodeJS. That time I used *sudo* to install all.

This is what I followed

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Recently I tried to create an AngularJS application, but it didn't create properly. Then I found I should not use sudo while installing nodejs, yeoman and Bower.

I searched and found the solution here [node-and-npm-in-30-seconds.sh](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814).

So first I uninstalled the NodeJS

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Then followed the first option provided in the link

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install # ok, fine, this step probably takes more than 30 seconds...
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

The last command didn't work. It showed

```
$ curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    51  100    51    0     0     63      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    63
sh: 1: Moved: not found
```

I googled and tried the following from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508817/2353403)

```
curl -O -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh
sh install.sh
```

It is showing the following error

```
npm cannot be installed without node.js.
Install node first, and then try again.

Maybe node is installed, but not in the PATH?
Note that running as sudo can change envs.

PATH=/home/myuser/local/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Why is it so? And how can I resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok this I have tried and worked for me

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make install
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: needed to do `sudo apt install python3-pip` and `pip3 install distutils`, otherwise `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local` fails

Answer (score 0):

Easier option is available here

https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation

Tip - For older vesion of OS, use older installation package.