# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND with Cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, aerogear

I am following the aerogear tutorial on https://aerogear.org/docs/guides/aerogear-cordova/AerogearCordovaPush/.

I have gone through this several times now and continue to have the same issue.

When deploying to Genymotion, and debugging using chrome, I see the following error:

```
file:///android_asset/www/plugins/aerogear-cordova-push/www/aerogear-push.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///android_asset/www/plugins/aerogear-cordova-push/www/aerogear.ajax.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cordova.js:1431 Uncaught Error: Module aerogear-cordova-push.AeroGear.ajax does not exist.
cordova.js:1185 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1178 Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
cordova.js:1178 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

## Observations

I notice that, when viewing in the Chrome inspector, that the plugin files are empty [image: plugin files are empty], yet in my local project there is contents for all the plugin files.

## Things I have tried

- Removing and re-adding aerogear plugs
- Doing a factory reset of the Genymotion vm.
- Uninstall and reinstall node using instructions on [Installing NodeJS without sudo in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025159/installing-nodejs-without-sudo-in-ubuntu)
- Reinstall cordova
- Reinstall genymotion
- Restart

## Details

- Node version v5.4.1
- Ubuntu version 15.10
- Cordova 5.4.1
- Android 5.1

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It appears that AeroGear plugin is not installed properly at the first glance what does your console say when you enter the "cordova plugin add" - command? Did you also try to add/install it locally(via download and referencing it via filesystem)?

Comment: @Blauharley - Ive tried installing the plugin using both 'cordova plugin add https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-pushplugin-cordova.git' and 'cordova plugin add org.jboss.aerogear.cordova.push'. Same result.  'cordova plugin add org.jboss.aerogear.cordova.push
Notice: org.jboss.aerogear.cordova.push has been automatically converted to aerogear-cordova-push and fetched from npm. This is due to our old plugins registry shutting down.
Fetching plugin "aerogear-cordova-push" via npm
Plugin "aerogear-cordova-push" already installed on android.

Comment: I just built a default android project and then installing aerogear-cordova-push plugin via "cordova plugin add https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-pushplugin-cordova.git" because the first one did not find this plugin in the cordova registry. I did not set up the whole push-functionality via googel for android but there are "aerogear-push.js" and "aerogear.ajax.js" files. My cordova version is 5.3.1. May be there is another problem why this plugin is not installed properly so I would suggest to update your dev-environment first and try to setup/run a default project. Good luck!

Comment: I also see the "aerogear-push.js" and "aerogear.ajax.js" files locally. Were you able to run your app without this error?

Comment: Basically yes, I was able to call push.register after deviceready has been fired. Are there really these two files within your platform/andriod directory? because your error logs say no.

Comment: Yes, in my local project I can see these files. Here is my [project structure](http://i.imgur.com/mEvxxi9.png). However, Im not sure if they get deployed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101469/discussion-between-magick-and-blauharley).

Comment: seems you have fixed your issue:  http://aerogear-users.1116366.n5.nabble.com/Aerogear-users-Failed-to-load-resource-tp487p491.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot say for sure why fixed it, but I suspect it was due to either:

- permissions
- corrupted dependencies

After reinstalling and re-setting permissions - and doing a restart - it worked correctly.

Comment: you mean permissions for android?